# Phonegap local notifications plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins

I am a beginner creating a phonegap app and I need to use local notifications. I used https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications but can't seem to get it to work. I'm totally lost on this one, so I'm giving everything I did, step by step.

What I did:
Navigated to `my_project_folder/plugins` and ran the command `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications`. The command executed without any errors.

A folder named `de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification` was now in my plugins folder. The line `<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications" />` automatically got added to `config.xml` .

In index.js of my app, for testing purposes I added the following code:

```
var d = new Date();
d.addSeconds(20); 
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 1999,
                title: 'Sample',
                message: 'checking',
                date: d
});
```

So I would get a notification 20 seconds after running the app. On running (in my browser) however I got the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined`.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this error? In some online examples the code begins with `window.plugin.notification.local.add({..` instead, but trying that gives the same error for me.

Comment: it will not work when u run the app from a browser, you need the device ready event before using the plugin and this is of course not possible from a  browser

Comment: also you are lacking basic knowledge on how cordova and plugins work

Comment: @Akis I'm learning. I'm making a basic app which is almost complete and this is the first third-party plugin I'm requiring, hence the confusion. Also I did try the code in the Phonegap android mobile app as well and it did not work.

executing it after deviceready event removes the error, but it now shows the warnings "unknown property: message" and "unknown property:date"

Comment: i am reading the documentation and i cannot find any properties with the name message or date. try to remove them

Comment: i think message should be replaced with text.

Comment: By replacing 'message' with 'text' (both are being used in the docs interchangeably as far as I understand) and 'date' with 'at'  it fixed the errors and warnings, but the notification still fails to show up when using the Phonegap mobile app. Should I compile an apk and try?

Comment: when u have time use the plugin i suggest in my answer, and the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var d = new Date();

//Are you sure about this addSeconds()?
d.addSeconds(20); 

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 1999,
                title: 'Sample',
                text: 'checking',
                trigger: {at: d}
});
```